# Magic squares with specific properties

Tags: co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

For what $n \geq 3$ does there exist an $n \times n$ matrix such that:

- All entries are in $(0, 1)$.
- Each row and column sums to $1$.
- Aside from the rows and columns, no other subsets of the entries sum to $1$.

EDIT: I had a comment about $n = 3$ likely not being possible, but I removed that now after some helpful comments.

Comment: What are the elements? For integers, the third condition does not make sense.

Comment: They're any real nonnegative numbers (the restrictions ensure they have to be in (0, 1) though I guess). I clarified this in the main post now.

Comment: Did not you mean [0,1) or zero entries are not allowed?

Comment: Theoretically they're fine, but if there is a $0$, then in that row we could just take $n - 1$ nonzero entries and they would sum to $1$ --- thus breaking the third condition. So there's no point in allowing them.

Comment: Indeed, when one has an nxn example with positive (nonzero) real entries, one computes all sums and sees which ones are close to 1.  Then multiply each row by 1 - epsilon_i and similarly each column, where the 2n epsilons  are distinct, much smaller than any entry in the array, and satisfy no algebraic relations.  Then augment the array by the epsilons to get an n+1 order example.

Comment: Actually, the row epsilons have to add up to the column epsilons, but no other relations should hold.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is an interesting idea. Though I believe you would have to do something slightly different because when you multiply the entries of a row by $1 - \epsilon_i$ you affect an entry in each column as well. Nonetheless, I think that's fixable. Can we show that there is some $n \geq 4$ that works though?

Comment: You should be able to do it starting from n=1.

Comment: In particular start with. 9 .1 .1 .9, and pick four epsilons each smaller than 10^{-3}, to multiply rows and then columns by 1 - an epsilon.

Comment: Just writing down numbers, on my first try I found $$\pmatrix{.14&.63&.23\cr.59&.26&.15\cr.27&.11&.62\cr}$$ so the case $n=3$ doesn't seem so hard.

Comment: For $n=3$ there's a 5-dimensional (affine) space of solutions,
and it seems that generically there's no other subset that sums to $1$,
so as long as you avoid a finite number of hyperplanes you're fine.

Comment: Oh thanks everyone! I don't understand which 5-dimensional affine space Noam Elkies is thinking about though. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: @Daishisan, because Noam's 5-dim affine space is actually 4-dimensional. And the rest indeed follows.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.

Comment: Why do you require $n \geq 3$? -- For $n = 1$ the problem becomes trivial (take the matrix with the only entry equal to $1$), and for $n = 2$ you can take e.g. the matrix $$\left(\begin{array} \ 1/3 & 2/3 \\ 2/3 & 1/3 \\ \end{array}\right)$$ -- or did I get something wrong?

Comment: Why you call it magic square (which is typically composed of integers)? It looks more like a doubly stochastic matrix http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix

Comment: if such matrices exist for all $n$ with moreover rational entries (which I would think is no constraint), another interesting question would be: What can be their smallest common denominator for given $n$? Equivalently: for a nxn matrix with entries in $\mathbb N$ and all row and column sums equal to $k$ such that no other entries sum up to $k$, what can be the smallest $k$ for given $n$?

Comment: re my last comment: if $n=3$, here is one for $k=22$:  $$\pmatrix{6&5&11\cr4&15&3\cr12&2&8\cr}$$. Who can do better?

Comment: @Wolfgang: Your example doesn't work: for example, $6 + 11 + 5 + 2 = 24$.

Comment: oh I see, even more than $n$ terms are allowed! This means in particular that the set of terms contained in the matrix must be sum-free.

Comment: Here's an example with $k=31$, which (if I haven't made any mistakes) is best possible:
$$\pmatrix{15 & 2 & 14\cr 3 & 19 & 9\cr 13 & 10 & 8\cr}$$

Comment: This was produced using an SMT solver (in this case MathSAT 5).

Comment: It doesn't have to be sum-free: what you do need is that whenever the sum of two entries is an entry, the sum is in the same row as one of the two and the same column as the other one.  For example, $13 + 2 = 15$ in my example above, with $15$ in the same column as $13$ and the same row as $2$.

Comment: yes I was aware of this possibility, which probably tends to occur more in the extremal cases. Of course I meant "essentially sum-free" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a matrix (integer version) can be constructed from a magic square, say with entries $1,\dots,n^2$, by adding suitable multiples of all $n\times n$ permutation matrices: e.g. take $N=n^2$ and add all $N^iP_i$, where $P_1, \dots,P_{n!}$ are in any order.
This is such a wasteful construction that the question raised in my comment above might deserve some attention: what are good upper bounds for the common  row and column sum of such a matrix?

Comment: Here's a $4 \times 4$ example for $k = 3302$ (not claimed to be optimal): 
$$ \pmatrix{2921 & 334 & 41 & 6\cr
191 & 1885 & 433 & 793\cr
125 & 382 & 1413 & 1382\cr
65 & 701 & 1415 & 1121\cr}$$

Comment: ... and now one with $k=1511$:
$$\pmatrix{268 & 207 & 977 & 59\cr 535 & 379 & 118 & 479\cr 73 & 153 & 332 & 953 \cr 635 & 772 & 84 & 20\cr}$$

Comment: Latest improvement: $k=913$:
$$ \pmatrix{153 & 440 & 26 & 294\cr
            307 & 42 & 128 & 436\cr
            318 & 200 & 285 & 110\cr
            135 & 231 & 474 & 73\cr}$$

Comment: @Robert: $k=480$
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 102& 132& 148& 98\\ 118& 78& 147& 137\\ 139& 170& 66 &105\\ 121 &100& 119& 140\end{matrix}\right)$$
Found by random hill-climbing.

Comment: And $k=460$:
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
82& 109& 103& 166\\ 94& 135& 125& 106\\ 102& 121& 133& 104\\ 182& 95& 99& 84
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: $k = 435$ using tabu search:
$$ \pmatrix{  109
  & 104
  & 148
  &  74
  \cr  85
  & 106
  &  82
  & 162
  \cr 123
  & 115
  & 111
  &  86
  \cr 118
  & 110
  &  94
  & 113
\cr}$$

Comment: $k=430$ (must be getting close to optimality...): $$ \pmatrix{ 62 & 152 & 104 & 112 \cr
153 & 90 & 94 & 93 \cr
102 & 89 & 132 & 107 \cr
113 & 99 & 100 & 118 \cr
}$$

Comment: @Robert, What happens if you subtract 43 from each of the entries of your latest example?  Gerhard "Hoping The Remainders Are Small" Paseman, 2014.07.22

Comment: @GerhardPaseman It doesn't work.  I get 12 subsets besides rows and columns that sum to 430 - 43*4 = 258, e.g. entries (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (3,2),(3,4): $47+51+50+46+64=258$.

Comment: ... and one for $k=428$: 
$$ \pmatrix{ 63 & 99 & 157 & 109 \cr
116 & 102 & 98 & 112 \cr
97 & 138 & 86 & 107 \cr
152 & 89 & 87 & 100 \cr
}$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the general integer version of the problem: given positive integers $n$ and $K$, find an $n \times n$ matrix of positive integers whose row and column sums are $K$, and no set of matrix elements that is not a row or column sums to $K$.  In principle, you can find a $K$ for which this is is possible as follows.

Consider producing your matrix $M$ as the sum of $K$ random permutation matrices, 
each of which is chosen independently and uniformly from the $n!$ possible permutations.  If $S$ is any subset of the entries that is not a row or column,
let $Y_S = \sum_{(i,j) \in S} M_{ij}$ be the sum of this subset of the entries of $M$.
Now the cardinality of the intersection of $S$ with a random permutation matrix 
is a random variable that is not a.s. $1$.  We can then estimate the probability
that $Y_S$, which is the sum of $K$ iid random variables with this distribution, is equal to $K$:
in general it should decay like $1/\sqrt{K}$ if $|S| = n$ (which makes the mean of the random variable $1$), and more rapidly if $|S| \ne n$.  As soon as $K$ is large enough that the expected number of subsets $S$ with $Y_S = K$ is less than $1$, we know that with positive probability all $Y_S \ne K$, and thus a solution with this $K$ is possible.